# Someone else's post has been removed, which caused loosing reputation points

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

As per title, I lost 2 points after someone else's post get removed (I cannot even remember my input in this removed thread) - couldn't find out why. What's the reason behind it and how does it work?

Comment: Might have been a suggested edit that got you the rep, if you were not otherwise involved. And you loose the rep because there is nothing anymore to have gained the rep for. [See this post on Meta SE for more relevant information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever a question gets removed, all reputation changes from that question are reversed (accepted answers, up- and downvoted answers etc.). This is `status-bydesign` because there is nothing left where you could gain/lose reputation from.

You probably lost 2 points because you suggested an edit which got accepted, and because the question is now removed you shouldn't own these points. Is this fair? I think it depends on how you look at it. Yes, you have spend time to improve a question and therefore you should earn some reputation. But on the other hand, your improvements still did not make the difference between keeping the question up: So I don't think you shouldn't own those reputation points.

Comment: Sounds reasonable indeed. I completely forgot I could gain reputation points from suggested edits there. Fair enough - this explains everything.